# In iteration, need to store line in a variable

Tags: powershell

so, first of all my scenario: Have a file, my script reads that file, counts the number of lines and reads the content line by line.

My script:

```
$lines = Get-Content C:\RDS\snaps.txt | Measure-Object -Line
$line = $lines.Lines
for($i=1; $i -le ($line-1); $i++)
{
   #Need to store a line in a variable
}
```

I need to be in this way:
For every "i" value which is less than or equal to ($line-1), I need to read the specific line.

Example: if i=1, means first line, I need to read the first line and store it in a variable. if i=($line-1), means the line above the last line, need to store that specific line and store it in the same variable.

How can this be done? I can't predict how many lines it will be there in the file. What change do I need to do in my script for this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple foreach loop to iterate over each line:

```powershell
$Content = Get-Content 'C:\RDS\snaps.txt'
$lineCount = 0;
$lastLine = ''
foreach ($line in $content) 
{
    $lineCount++
    # Insert your condition to store the lastline: if ($lineCount -eq ...)
    $lastLine = $line
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the if script should be like this:
if($lineCount -eq "lastline"){}else{}
But I can't predict how many lines it will be there in the file. How can I check if $lineCount is last line.?

Comment: $content.Length gives you the line count of your file, so you could use something like if ($content.Length -le $lineCount) (-le means less equal)

Answer (score 1):

this question is really not clear, but if you just want to read a specific line, you don't need a for loop. In fact [get-content](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh849787(v=wps.620).aspx) will return a collection (array) of object for each line. So  the n<sup>th</sup> line can be accessed it with  `$content[n-1]`.

So

```
$content=Get-Content C:\RDS\snaps.txt
$content[0] #firstline
$content[-2]# the line before the last line
```